# Parallel Stream for inserting data on startup

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm just wondering if it's possible to create a parallelStream inside a startup-event function. I discover quarkus at the moment and for testing i have to read a file and insert its files into the database on startup. Whenever is try to use a `parallelStream` instead of a normal one, i get `ACCESS_VIOLATION_EXCEPTION`.

Here's some Code so you can imagine what i'm doing. This example works.

```java
void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) throws Exception {
    // Parsing the file, getting the iterator
    it.readAll().stream().forEach(this::operateEntry);
}

@Transactional
void operateEntry(Entry entry) {
    // Performing the database actions for a single entry
}
```

Using the same example but this time with an parallel stream results in an error:

```java
void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) throws Exception {
    // Parsing the file, getting the iterator
    it.readAll().parallelStream().forEach(this::operateEntry);
}
```

And the error message

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd5e59bf40, pid=15880, tid=20388
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.1+13) (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1ebf40]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\knowledge\curator-service\target\hs_err_pid15880.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

I understand that parsing a bigger amount of data on every quarkus startup might not a realistic use-case. However i would like to understand why this does not work. I'm thankful for any advice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't work because it crashed due to a bug in the VM.

Comment: Access violation is usually an indication of problem in native code - usually badly addressed memory. If the database access relies on some external library (DLL or SO), it may have a bug.

Comment: That's not a Quarkus issue, something wrong is being triggered in your JDK. I see you're using a very old build of JDK11, try updating?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've tried updating to the current version of OpenJDK-11 but it still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try do to do something simple (like print) in your operateEntry function to be sure that it is not a problem with your database access.

I don't think that this is the good approach to solve your problem, parallelStream to access database often lead to the kinf of problem you are actually facing.

Another approach might be to use parallel aproach to read files, but a single transaction to commit in database.